# Stack Exchange Valued Associate CGI enhancements?

Tags: discussion, moderators, fun, feature-request-process

Does [Nick Craver](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/135201/nick-craver) have a souvenir Cricket bat with `[STATUS-DECLINED]` engraved on it, or was this image enhanced with CGI?

[image: Animated GIF. Nick Craver, Stack Exchange Associate, swings a cricket bat. The bat is engraved with the phrase STATUS DECLINED.]

Answer (score 19):

Only one way to know. Come here and find out.

Comment: That's a paddlin'...

Comment: I want to see Jeff and his giant S. Agh, doesn't sound good. But you understand right? :-)

Comment: Jeff needs an animated image with him wielding a giant S on that page. See to it, Nick.

Answer (score 4):

It was definitely not enhanced.  The [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) bat of Nick's is just the start of it.  And as it turns out, Stack Exchange has a Zombie Apocalypse team in its ranks.

Mouseover for live video of their team.  These videos are based on real life, viewer discretion is advised.

Ben Dumke-von der Ehe

> [image]

Korneel Bouman

> [image]

David Fullerton

> [image]

Oh yeah. Zombies declined.

Comment: I never did get my unicorn turned into a hoodie.  I wonder if that's where his unnatural owl powers come from.

Comment: I want to put on record that my animation *is* real life. I insisted on doing it without photoshop help. If you look closely, you should be able to see it. /cc @AdamDavis